# Having trouble with this trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

Having trouble solving this trigonometry problem I came across. Any help would be greatly appreciated

If $\sqrt{3}cot^2\theta -4cot\theta + \sqrt{3} = 0 $

Find the value of $cot^2\theta + tan^2\theta$

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: @Abhishekstudent I got the answer. Given in a nice and concise proof below. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Good to know! Best Of Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:-

Let,$\cot\theta=x$

So, $\sqrt3 x^2-4x+\sqrt3=0$

$\implies\sqrt3x^2-3x-x+\sqrt3=0$

$\implies(\sqrt3x-1)(x-\sqrt3)=0$

So,$\cot\theta=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}$ or $\color{blue}{\sqrt3}$

So,$\tan\theta=\color{red}{\sqrt3}$ or $\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}$

Comment: Okay wow, that was really fast. Thanks so much! I can see what I was missing. It turned out to be a simple quadratic! But thank you so much! I love this community :')

Comment: @AmanBhargava Welcome to Math SE!!If you like my answer you can thank me by upvoting and accepting the answer!!

Comment: I surely will! It doesn't allow me to do so within 10 mins, but I will surely upvote and accept your answer. Nice to know that this isn't a hostile community like Stackoverflow. People here are really friendly and helpful!

Comment: @AmanBhargava Thanks!!You see,I also had a lot of problem when I began in StackOverflow....its not that they are hostile but StackOverflow is mostly for high end experts so beginners like we are have problem in adapting at first....

Comment: @AmanBhargava 10th Grade (I'm from India)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45309/discussion-between-aman-bhargava-and-tatan).